# problem with iphone 3G and baseband 06.15.00

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone3G. I did the mistake to connect it to itunes and update to latest software 4.2.1 so it locked and it does not accept my SIM card. So I upgraded baseband to ipads 06.15.00 with redsnow and activated, jailbraked it and unlock it with ultrasnow. Everything was perfect [SIZE="4"]BUT then i did the most stupid thing.[/SIZE] 
I connected it again to itunes hoping to load my photos from a backup. But things didnt work in a good way. It locked again. I dont know the current firmware that it has. Now i cant jailbreak it with redsnow and itunes wont restore to any IPSW because itunes cant downgrade the baseband. The phone is not even activated right now and i cant run cydia to unlock it.
PLEASE HELP!

Comment: This reads like a question for Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last resort, try reseting the iPhone. It should say how to do this in the instructions. Contacting Apple might have been a better idea than jailbreaking.